# Composing the function `Printf.sprintf` with another

Tags: types, ocaml

I have a lot of occurrences of plugging in the result of `Printf.sprintf` into another function (say) `f`.  I have been trying to define the composition `printf` of these two, like this:

```
let printf : 'a 'b. ('a,unit,string) format -> 'b =
  (fun fmt -> Printf.sprintf fmt) |> f
```

However, this does not typecheck, and nor does the version thereof with several applications of `Obj.magic`.  What is the right way of getting such a "custom printf"?

Comment: Try it without the `'a 'b.` in front.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `Obj.magic`.

Due to the special typing of format strings to achieve variadic `printf`, you cannot write such things using simple function composition:

```
let sprintf_then_f fmt args ... = f (Printf.sprintf fmt args ...)
```

To overcome this difficulty, `Printf` provides continuation style functions with `k` (kontinuation) in the names such as `Printf.ksprintf`.  Please use them:

```
val ksprintf : (string -> 'd) -> ('a, unit, string, 'd) format4 -> 'a
(** Same as [sprintf] above, but instead of returning the string,
   passes it to the first argument.
   @since 3.09.0
*)
```

Comment: Note that since 4.02, format string are internally implemented with GADTs, and "%s" is just syntactic sugar for "CamlinternalFormatBasics.(Format(String(No_padding,End_of_format),"%s")), thus the only-magic left in the typing of format string is the type-directed disambiguation of format string and string literals .